# JS expression in R Shiny conditionalPanel to find substring in dropdown with multiple set to TRUE

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

In the following code I would like to show the `result` text output only when an item is selected from `dropdown1` containing the substring 'box'. The following works fine when `multiple` is set to FALSE but not when set to TRUE.

How can I  modify the JS expression in the conditionalPanel function to achieve this behaviour with multiple set to TRUE in the selectInput? I presume this is pretty simple but use R mainly and JS hardly at all.

```
library(shiny)
         ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput(inputId = "dropdown1",
              label = "dropdown",
              choices = c("green box","red circle", "blue box", "yellow circle"),
              selected = "",
              multiple = TRUE   ),
     conditionalPanel(condition = "input.dropdown1.indexOf('box') >= 0",
                   
                   textOutput("result")
                      )    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
     output$result <- renderText({
    paste("Result:", input$dropdown1)   }) }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the answer. The JS expression I needed was:

```
"input.dropdown1.some(function(x) { return x.indexOf('box') >= 0; })"
```

Full app as follows:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput(inputId = "dropdown1",
              label = "dropdown",
              choices = c("green box","red circle", "blue box", "yellow circle"),
              selected = "",
              multiple = TRUE   ),
     conditionalPanel(condition = "input.dropdown1.some(function(x) { return x.indexOf('box') >= 0; })",
                   
                   textOutput("result")
                      )    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
     output$result <- renderText({
    paste("Result:", input$dropdown1)   }) }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```